# If a CSS rule changes, does the browser need to be refreshed

Tags: html, css, css-reset

If I have changed a CSS rule via javascript, do I need to do anything to "refresh" the browser to redisplay the current page using the updated rules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No--a refresh isn't necessary--and if it did occur it would restore the document to its original state.

The change should take place immediately (setting display: none, for example). Use FireFox plugin FireBug (http://getfirebug.com/) or the IE Developer Toolbar (built into IE8 and available as a free plugin for previous versions) to dynamically view the HTML to ensure the change you think is taking place is actually occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Changing CSS properties on the fly via JavaScript **should** automatically make the change in the user's web browser unless there is something wrong with your script of if the user has JavaScript turned off.